# How to deal with non-termination error in Cubical Agda

Tags: agda, dependent-type, cubical-type-theory

I am using the usual coinductive definition of the M-type, defined below.

```
record M (S : Set) (Q : S → Set) : Set where
  coinductive
  constructor sup-M
  field
    shape : S
    pos : Q shape → M S Q
open M
```

I define a family `Pos` over `M`, which has specified target types (namely the target types use `sup-M` and aren't generic for any `m : M`).

```
data Pos : M S Q → Set where
    here : {s : S} {f : Q s → M S Q} → Pos (sup-M s f) 
    below : {s : S} {f : Q s → M S Q} → (q : Q s) → Pos (f q) → Pos (sup-M s f)
```

Say that for fixed `S : Set`, `Q : S → Set`, `X Y : Set`, `s : S`, `h : Q s → Y`, `g : Y → X`, I define the function below going into `M`.

```
β₁ : Y → M S Q
shape (β₁ y) = s
pos (β₁ y) = β₁ ∘ h
```

Then if I want to define a function `β₂ : (y : Y) → Pos (β₁ y) → X`, I'm not able to pattern-match on the second argument because it's not of the form `Pos (sup-M s f)`. I can get around this in a few ways, one of which is by noting that in Cubical Agda we have (propositional) eta-equality for `M`:

```
M-eta-eq : {S : Set} {Q : S → Set} (m : M S Q) → sup-M (shape m) (pos m) ≡ m
shape (M-eta-eq m i) = shape m
pos (M-eta-eq m i) = pos m
```

So I can define a helper function `β₂' : (y : Y) → Pos (sup-M s (β₁ ∘ h)) → X` which allows pattern matching, and then define `β₂` in terms of `β₂'` using the fact that `M-eta-eq (β₁ y) : sup-M s (β₁ ∘ h) ≡ β₁ y`.

```
β₂' : (y : Y) → Pos (sup-M s (β₁ ∘ h)) → X
β₂' y here = g y
β₂' y (below q p) = β₂' (h q) (subst Pos (sym (M-eta-eq (β₁ (h q)))) p)

β₂ : (y : Y) → Pos (β₁ y) → X
β₂ y p = β₂' y (subst Pos (sym (M-eta-eq (β₁ y))) p)
```

The problem with this is that it raises a non-terminating error, presumably because Agda can't tell that `subst Pos (sym (M-eta-eq (β₁ (h q)))) p` is structurally smaller than `below q p`. So my question is:

> Can I prove to Agda that `β₂'` terminates? Perhaps something making use of `subst-filler`?

P.S. I have tried other approaches, like defining `β₂` using the eliminator of `Pos`, or adding an equality of the form `m ≡ sup-M s f` to the constructors of `Pos`, and then having the target types be of type `Pos m`. While I was able to define `β₂` successfully in both cases, both approaches introduced many `subst`s and `transport`s to proofs of equality involving `β₂` that I have to do later on. I am wondering if there is a better way to define `Pos`, especially since I know inductive families are still not fully supported in Cubical Agda.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally try to avoid [green slime](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/what-are-some-good-bad-examples-of-green-slime) both in function arguments and in constructor return types: indices that yield difficult unification problems (in this case, `M` doesn't have definitional eta equality, so even `sup-M` is difficult).

Things go smoothly if you use variables instead:

```
  data Pos : M S Q → Set where
      here : {m : M S Q} → Pos m
      below : {m : M S Q} → (q : Q (shape m)) → Pos (pos m q) → Pos m

  β₁ : M S Q
  shape β₁ = s
  pos β₁ _ = β₁

  β₂ : (y : Y) → Pos β₁ → X
  β₂ y here = g y
  β₂ y (below q p) = β₂ (h q) p

  _ : {y : Y} → β₂ y here ≡ g y
  _ = refl
```

Comment: That's a great idea! Similar to how I defined `β₂` using the eliminator of `Pos`. Unfortunately though, I'm still stuck on a later proof if I use this definition. So follow up question: how would I be able to prove something like `β₂ y (subst Pos (M-eta-eq (β₁ y)) here) ≡ g y` using this definition? I know I can use something like `(subst-filler Pos (M-eta-eq (β₁ y)) here)`, but then I get stuck applying `β₂ y` to both of them. 

Thanks a lot for your help, it's appreciated.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternative definition of `Pos` that makes your desired equality definitional.

Comment: In fact this new definition removes the need for `β₂'` shenanigans.